# How to optimize this simple bash shell script?

Tags: shell, apache-kafka

I found that my script wasn't efficient enough.

Can I write this script better?

I want to output `kafka-console-consumer.sh` execution time, how do I write it?

The input result can be `kafka_Check|consumer:0|consumer_time:0.3s`

```
#!/bin/bash
result=""
vesrion=`ps -ef|grep -v grep|grep -o "kafka.\{,20\}[0-9]-sources.jar"|awk -F '-' '{print $2}'|cut -d . -f 1,-3|tr -d .`
OUT_FLAG() {
        local check_value=$1
        local result_value=$2
        if [ "${check_value}" -eq 0 ];then
             result="$result|${result_value}:0"
        else
             result="$result|${result_value}:1"
        fi
}

get_kafka_home(){
        local kafka_home_count=`ps -ef|grep kafka-tool|grep -v grep| wc -l`
        if [ $kafka_home_count -ge 1 ];then
        kafka_home=`ps -ef|grep kafka\.kafka|grep -v grep | awk -F '/bin/../libs' '{print $2}'|awk -F ':' '{print $2}'`
        else
          echo "could not found kafka_home."
          exit 1
        fi
}


consumer(){
        local consumer_mes=0
        TOPIC=`$kafka_home/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list|grep -v "__consumer_offsets"|grep -m 1 "[a-zA-Z]"`
        if [ ${vesrion} -gt 0102 ]; then
                timeout -k 3s 3s $kafka_home/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic $TOPIC --from-beginning --max-messages 1 &>/dev/null
                consumer_mes=$?
                OUT_FLAG ${consumer_mes} "consumer_flag"
        else
                timeout -k 3s 3s $kafka_home/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic $TOPIC --from-beginning --new-consumer --max-messages 1 &>/dev/null
                consumer_mes=$?
                OUT_FLAG ${consumer_mes} "consumer_flag"
        fi

}

main(){
        get_kafka_home
        config_file="$kafka_home/config/server.properties"
        if [[ $(ss -ntupl|grep -w '9092' &>/dev/null) -ne 0 ]]&&[[ $(ss -ntupl|grep -w '2181' &>/dev/null) -ne 0 ]]
            then
                exit 1
        else
            consumer
        fi
        echo "Kafka_Check$result"
}

main
```

Comment: Belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have you used https://shellcheck.net ?

Comment: The Kafka CLI version doesn't need to match the server version, so there is no need to check it